# Can a delta wing fighter engage an arrestor net without its main landing gear?

Tags: landing, fighter, emergency-procedures

A delta wing fighter aircraft with underwing drop tanks while landing loses its main landing gear, but the nose wheel is extended. Is it an option for the pilot to engage the barrier net of type EP-15 or MENA-30 at the end of the runway, or will the pilot eject?

Which is the safest and why?

Comment: What is the net for in this scenario? I would think all of that metal scraping along the runway would provide more than enough braking power.

Comment: Why is the delta wing a factor here?

Answer (score 3):

In August 2009, a Saab Gripen pilot forgot to extend the landing gear, and walked away from the landing unharmed. And this was without any preparation of any kind.

There is no reason to eject from a perfectly good airplane just because you can't extend the landing gear. Belly landings are a pretty "routine emergency" (if that term makes sense).

The metal scraping across the runway will probably generate as much if not more friction than the tires would, so the risk of a runway overshoot is rather negligible, and there is no need to use any arresting gear at the end of the runway.

What *could* make sense, though, is to use arresting gear at the beginning of the runway, if the aircraft is equipped with an arresting hook and the runway is equipped with arresting wires.

It might make sense to drop the drop tanks if they are full.

The delta wing does not play a role here, this applies more or less to all kinds of wing planforms.

Comment: Well, I am told Delta wings are for unstable aircraft hence belly landing is not recommended. Here actaully Iam looking for information on whether or not to engage the Arrester Barrier Net of EP15 type if aircraft is not rolling on main landing gears.

Comment: The presence on nose landing gear provides an angle of attack for the wing to generate lift and hence the aircraft doesnot lose speed in the absence of  brakes.